# Are "Warranty voided if removed"-labels illegal?

Tags: united-states, hardware

[NPR](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2018/04/11/601582169/warranty-void-if-removed-as-it-turns-out-feds-say-those-warnings-are-illegal) wrote in 2018

> The Federal Trade Commission says they're [Warranty voided if removed labels] illegal.

- Are "Warranty voided if removed"-labels illegal?
- What, if any, is the practical effect of removing the label?

Comment: Like with many Law questions, this is a matter of (legal) opinion until it is tried in a court. You already have one appropriate expert (the FTC) giving their opinion. What are you hoping for in an answer? If you want opinions from the peanut gallery, Law.SE might be a better site.

Comment: @Oddthinking Documented instances where a) insertion of sticker is cited as cause in court case or consumer grievance organ. (What ever those may be) b) Removal of sticker has been cited as reason for not honoring warranty. (And documentation further action)

Comment: Addition to b: cases where sticker was removed, and warranty was honored despite the threat.

Comment: @close voter. Not notable? NPR isn't notable?

Comment: @Oddthinking FTC statements are more than just expert opinion because the relevant law gives the FTC certain powers.  https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/chapter-50 The term "commission" is defined to mean the FTC.

Comment: I would say this is a question for law.se and not really on topic here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it already has an authoritative answer embedded in the link it refers to: https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/news/press-releases/2018/04/ftc-staff-warns-companies-it-illegal-condition-warranty-coverage-use-specified-parts-or-services

Comment: @DavePhD interesting. I was not aware of this. Maybe I wasn't alone.

Comment: The sticker is sometimes placed such that you cannot open the case without breaking the sticker. So it means you have opened the case, and they are in effect saying that opening the case will void the warranty, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @WeatherVane But removing the sticker still does not invalidate the warranty, even if the company would like that. If the product is broken, it does not matter if the user scratched the surface, added their own sticker, or removed a sticker placed on the product (such as a Windows 10 sticker).

Comment: @pipe what matters is that the customer either attempted to repair it themself, or actually caused the malfunction by tampering with it. If the notice is removed, it's a likely sign (with due warning) that they did. Then it doesn't matter whether the customer attempted to repair it or caused the problem by tampering. It amounts to "terms of use".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [SE Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: It’s unclear exactly what you mean. Whether it is actually illegal to put the sticker there, or whether it can just be safely ignored without any consequences. Usually the warranty is voided if you actually damage the product.

Comment: @gnasher729 After finding out the fact that it is indeed illegal, I'm more interested in if the sticker actually means anything. Figuring out how to edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Terms of use" i.e. a civil contract, cannot override statutory rights, which is what the FTC is pointing out. Same thing with the 2-year EU warranty when companies were saying they warranty only for 1 year.

Comment: I've only seen these stickers covering access to the inner workings of the device. Is this what you're talking about or something else? These are to prevent you from going in and tinkering with the device yourself - it would seem unfair to force them to honour a warranty when you'd taken the thing apart and messed around with the insides...

Comment: @komodosp it doesn't. If you open it up and break it, they don't have to honour the warranty. If you open it up and *don't* break it, they still do.

Comment: @Caleth - well depending on the nature of the damage of course, but once you've opened it up, it could be very difficult to tell if the fault was because of something you've done or a pre-existing problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

They are illegal under the Magnuson-Moss Warranty Act. ifixit has a great writeup, with all the sources, including the FTC:
https://www.ifixit.com/News/11748/warranty-stickers-are-illegal

Unfortunately, in *practice*, currently **No**

Unlike Lemon Laws for cars, the act does not have cost-shifting provisions. If GM doesn't take back their 20K lemon and you sue them and win, all your costs will be paid. Because of that, lawyers will take the cases for free and manufacturers settle quickly(because dragging out a case they know they will lose, just increases their costs when they do). If Apple doesn't honor their warranty on a 2K laptop and you sue, you will win, but Apple will drag it out for years, you will pay 100s of thousands of dollars and all you'll get is the cost of the warranty.

A law is only as good as it's enforcement.

Comment: I'm not sure the penultimate para is entirely accurate. It is certainly possible to win the cost of litigation too in certain jurisdictions. Albeit it being on a case-by-case basis makes the plaintiffs less likely to sue. (Not Trump, though, ha ha.)

Comment: BTW according to Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Magnuson%E2%80%93Moss_Warranty_Act&oldid=1177341928#Remedies_under_the_Act) on this law "one of the key aids to the effectiveness of the act is that a prevailing plaintiff may recover reasonable costs of suit, including attorney fees." YMMV. The main issue that I see reading the actual law is that the fee recovery in question only applies if the base loss (sans litigation) exceeds $50,000.

Comment: Actually, unless something has changed since 1986 "Conventional application of U.C.C. remedies will not, however, permit the warranty plaintiff to be made whole, because he ordinarily will not be
entitled to reimbursement for expenses incurred in retaining counsel and bringing his claim. 
troublemakers. Therefore, although authority exists to the contrary, the
American rule precludes the recovery of attorney's fees as incidental or
consequential damages under the U.C.C."

Comment: "This result derives from the American rule prohibiting
an award of attorney's fees to the successful ligitant without a statutory or
contractual provision expressly authorizing such an award. The U.C.C. does
not explicitly authorize attorney's fees, and the usual seller-oriented purchase
contract is unlikely to be so generous as to grant attorney's fees to successful." https://www.repository.law.indiana.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2153&context=ilj

Comment: OTOH for example, there certainly are state-level exceptions for some kinds of warranty: "In an August 2017 opinion, the Arizona Supreme Court ruled that attorney fees shall be awarded to the prevailing party in a lawsuit alleging a breach of the implied warranty of workmanship and habitability. The court ruled that the awarding of attorney fees can stem from either the fee provision in the construction contract or in Arizona law." https://www.lang-klain.com/blog/implied-warranty3

Comment: Your source (basically a blog by a "content creator") is worse than OP's source (NPR). Both fail to mention that Magnuson-Moss exempts companies that provide repairs under warranty for free, meaning the stickers are likely legal on many products. The FTC press release does mention that. The reason this question went unanswered is that the legal situation is unclear. Your answer is what people want to hear, but it isn't the truth.